# Flutter TextField set textAlign for each line separately

Tags: flutter, text-alignment, flutter-textformfield, flutter-text

In flutter, Is there any way to set textAlign for each line separately?
I want something like telegram app text input:

[image]

In telegram, if the line starts with a rtl language, text align is right otherwise it is left.

I try these ways so far:

1- [auto_direction package](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_direction)

2- Checking text with `intl.Bidi.detectRtlDirectionality` and set textAlign dynamically.

But all of these ways sets the textAlign for all lines, I want to set it separately for each line.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap each line with align widget separately and give alignment property as per your requirement

Comment: That's the problem, how align each line in text field widget?

Comment: How many lines inside the textfield you want to align? You can align individual textfields like this Align(
                        child: TextField(),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                      )

Comment: It based on user input

Comment: Okay iterate and align individually till the length of user input is reached

Answer (score -1):

Detect language and change `textDirection` and `textAlign` properly.
You can detect languages with `RegExp` class.

```
  var persian = RegExp(r'[\u0600-\u06FF]');
  var english = RegExp(r'[a-zA-Z]');
  var arabic = RegExp(r'[\u0750-\u077F]');
  var chinese = RegExp(r'[\u4E00-\u9FFF]');
  var japanese = RegExp(r'[\u3040-\u309F]');
  var korean = RegExp(r'[\uAC00-\uD7AF]');
```

Use `onChanged` call back property of `TextField` to detect language.

Comment: It seems that you didn't read the question, this change the align for all lines not for one line.

Comment: Then I think to copy the `textField` from the source code and inspect how it aligns each line.